# SQL Server : Cursor Update Issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a custom function to split a string:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] 
 (
     @str NVARCHAR(MAX), 
     @separator CHAR(1)
 )
 RETURNS TABLE 
 AS
 return (
 with tokens(p, a, b) AS (
     select 
         cast(1 as bigint), 
         cast(1 as bigint), 
         charindex(@separator, @str)
     union all
     select
         p + 1, 
         b + 1, 
         charindex(@separator, @str, b + 1)
     from tokens
     where b > 0
 )
 select
     p-1 ItemIndex,
     substring(
         @str, 
         a, 
         case when b > 0 then b-a ELSE LEN(@str) end) 
     AS Item
 from tokens
 );
```

(credit for that code goes to someone else on Stack Overflow who I can't remember)

This works fine in another script I use to do the same thing.

Ultimately this makes up part of an ETL, with the aim of taking this:

```
ID | Title
1  | Mrs K
```

Into This:

```
ClientContactRef | Title | Forename
1                | Mrs   | K
```

My code looks like this:

```
DECLARE @Title varchar(max)
DECLARE @ThirdPartyRef int

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT Title, ID FROM [Abacus].[dbo].[ThirdParty]
WHERE Title IS NOT NULL

OPEN cur

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Title, @ThirdPartyRef

UPDATE Migrate.ClientContact
SET Title = LEFT(Item,60)
FROM SplitString(@Title,CHAR(32))
WHERE ItemIndex = 0
AND Migrate.ClientContact.ClientContactRef = @ThirdPartyRef

UPDATE Migrate.ClientContact
SET Forename = LEFT(Item,60)
FROM SplitString(@Title,CHAR(32))
WHERE ItemIndex = 1
AND Migrate.ClientContact.ClientContactRef = @ThirdPartyRef

END

CLOSE Cur
Deallocate Cur

GO
```

As mentioned I use this elsewhere to split out an address into 5 components (which I also need to do here) but I get the same problem - namely that there doesn't seem to be any output from split string inside the cursor, so all my target fields end up as null.

The splitstring function works outside of the cursor on a single row as expected, but once inside the cursor nothing appears to be being returned.  I attempted to put a temp table inside the cursor to catch the output of splitstring, and there wasn't any.

Thanks in advance

Simon

Comment: You should not be using a cursor, and there is no reason to update columns separately, join your tables on their ids and just do a single update statement

Comment: Why use a cursor for this? Which SQL Server version are you using? In SQL Server 2016 and later you can convert the string to a json array by replacing delimieters with `","` and extract specific elements with `JSON_VALUE`. You can do the same in previous versions by converting them to XML. Finally, ETL is a *lot* easier if you use an ETL tool like SSIS. You could extract the string's components with a `Derived Column` transformation in every SQL Server version

Comment: Hi Both - Using SQL 2014 here, and did look at the XML conversion idea in the past.  Fortunately this is an ETL job that only needs to run once in anger (a data migration), so using SSIS to run all my scripts, but nothing more complex than that (but potentially a good option).  I seem to recall trying to do this previously with a non cursor update statement, but ran into problems - I might give it another go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve what you are trying to do, in a single update statement and without a cursor.

```
UPDATE MCC SET 
    MCC.Title = CASE WHEN SST.ItemIndex = 0 THEN LEFT(SST.Item,60) ELSE MCC.Title END
    ,MCC.ForeName = CASE WHEN SST.ItemIndex = 1 THEN LEFT(SST.Item,60) ELSE MCC.ForeName END
FROM Migrate.ClientContact AS MCC
    JOIN Abacus.dbo.ThirdParty AS ATP
        ON MCC.ClientContactRef = ATP.ID
    CROSS APPLY SplitString(ATP.Title,CHAR(32)) AS SST
WHERE SST.ItemIndex IN (0,1)
;
```

Comment: So this worked for the Title part, but the first initial seems to be lost (all forenames stay as null) - I suspect this must be an issue with the char(32) separator.

Comment: If you want to test your output of the Split String, just run a SELECT ATP.ID,ATP.Title,SST.ItemIndex, SST.Item FROM Abacus.dbo.ThirdParty AS ATP CROSS APPLY SplitString(ATP.Title,CHAR(32)) AS SST ORDER BY ATP.ID,SST.ItemIndex

Comment: Here's a good article involving splitting strings by Aaron Bertrand, it references 2016 but has links to older articles that may be helpful as well. https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split

Comment: So the output from that is fine - getting the split as I would expect it to look

Comment: Slight fix needed - The cross apply had to be run twice, once to populate the title, and once to populate the forename.  Once I did this it worked fine.  Thanks!